# Rails problems with :remote=>true

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, kaminari

Hi I am using Kaminari for pagination in my Rails3 application, however when I use the ajax command in my view `<%= paginate @items, :remote=>true %>` it places data-remote="true" into the HTML but the browsers don't do anything IE and Firefox both behave the same way.  Any help?

Here is the output HTML of my javascripts:

```
<script src="/javascripts/jquery.js?1311949985" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/jquery_ujs.js?1311949985" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/jquery-ui.js?1309364376" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/jquery.flexselect.js?1312229948" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/jquery.min.js?1311949985" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/liquidmetal.js?1312229948" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/rails.js?1313595592" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/application.js?1312396308" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Check the console in browser to make sure, there is no js error, preventing any further execution of js.

Comment: rails.js is causing my data-confirm to be displayed twice and sending data twice when :remote=>true is not set

Comment: @rubish there was one error...I removed it and error persists.

Comment: Do you have any other ajax requests working in your app? And might be that you are including both "jquery" and "jquery.min" and also "rails.js" and "jquery_ujs.js" which is newer better version of "rails.js"

Comment: No, there is no other Ajax calls.  I will try removing those two: rails.js and jquery.min.

Comment: @rubish this failed to work too.  Error persists after removing rails.js and jquery.min.js

Comment: Sorry, nothing more I can find which seems the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe i did not have the HTML doctype declared, but the XHTML doctype and this was the root.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to have UJS (Unobtrusive JavaScript) loaded in properly for those attributes to work. Usually this is a combination of jQuery and `rails.js` that are required to add this functionality.

It's easy to forget to insert these into the `<head>` section of your layout.